# How can we get our default off-topic close reason back?

Tags: support

We added some custom reasons for off-topic and it removed the default one.  So as a workaround, we've had to manually add the default reason.  How can we get our default off-topic close reason back?  This way, we would then be able to add a 3rd off-topic reason.

Answer (score 1):

By adding it as custom reason.

> The way to get the reason back, while preserving the custom reason, is to add the default reason (or something resembling it) as another custom reason too.

[Why doesn't the default "off topic" close reason appear when you add a custom close reason?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231062/226837)